Firefox Browser doesnot support to run Flutter Web app
I am trying to run Flutter web app in firefox browser. But it is not showing in devices list, only showing chrome and edge browsers. How to add Firefox in devices list and run flutter web application.
Any suggestions would be great.

Try run your app with command flutter run -d web-server
Paste the url that it shows in console to Firefox
Checkout this solution

If you think the linked answer solves the issue, then why don't you just close-vote as a dupe?
